# Server Side Row Model

Tags: angular, overlay, ag-grid, server-side, enterprise

I want the default loading overlay to keep appearing while serverSideRowModel functions are called and suppress the loading spinner that appears while data fetch in my angular application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can control [overlays](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-overlays) manually.

to show:

```
gridapi.showLoadingOverlay();
```

to hide:

```
gridapi.hideOverlay();
```